# How to write CMOS time?

Tags: bios, time, ntp, cmos

I have a fairly new computer (i.e. not likely BIOS battery problem), and *every* time I boot/reboot the time is off by ~2 seconds. To fix this, I every time have to set my time manually, and then run NPT synchronization.

How do I write the current Windows time into CMOS? My motherboard is an MSI Z370-A (Intel Z370 chipset).

Comment: Whenever you set the time in Windows, it should update the time in BIOS.  Additionally, if your computer is off by ~2 seconds *every* time you boot, something is wrong.  Have you checked if your BIOS is at the latest version?

Comment: Yes, BIOS has been flashed to the latest version three weeks ago.